# Rails 5 API - controller update action sometimes does not reflect database changes (cache issue)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, controller

I have 2 simple models in a has_many relationship. A Template has_many TemplateItems. A Template has a template_type which can be one of two values ('template' or 'checklist').

For brevity I have removed non-relevant code.

**template.rb**

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :template_items, -> { order('sort ASC') }, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_items, allow_destroy: true

  # Enums
  enum template_type: {template: 0, checklist: 1}
  enum status: {not_started: 0, started: 1, completed: 2}

  # Callbacks
  before_save :set_status, unless: :is_template? # only care about status for checklists

  def is_template?
    return self.template_type == 'template'
  end

  def set_status
    completed = 0
    self.template_items.each do |item|
      completed += 1 if item.is_completed
    end
    case completed
      when 0
        self.status = Template.statuses[:not_started]
      when 1..(self.template_items.length - 1)
        self.status = Template.statuses[:started]
      when self.template_items.length
        self.status = Template.statuses[:completed]
    end
  end
end
```

**template_item.rb**

```
class TemplateItem < ApplicationRecord  

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :template

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :template
end
```

When a client sends an update to Template Controller, it includes the template_items nested:

**templates_controller.rb**

```
def template_params 
  params.require(:template).
    permit(:id, :account_id, :list_type, :name, :title, :info, :status, 
      template_items_attributes: 
      [:id, :template_id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type, :sort, :_destroy])
end
```

Notice that one of the attributes of an item is called sort. Notice also that the sort order is used in the `Template` model to sort the `template_items` (see the `has_many` line).

If a client resorts the template_items, the following update action is called:

**templates_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    if @template.update(template_params)
      render json: @template, serializer: TemplateSerializer, status: :ok 
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(@template.errors), status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The strange behaviour is that the database is always updated (verified in the logs and in the db) but **sometimes** the render does not render the new sort order but instead renders the previous sort order.

Here is the log when the action incorrectly returns the previous data:

```
I, [2018-02-20T20:22:55.997835 #1852]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::TemplatesController#update as JSON
...parameters here...
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.002965 #1852] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "rmcsharry+owner@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.115190 #1852] DEBUG -- :   Template Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(templates.name) ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "f9f6bca2-cb84-4349-8546-ca38026db407"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.121995 #1852] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.129177 #1852] DEBUG -- :   TemplateItem Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "template_items".* FROM "template_items" WHERE "template_items"."template_id" = $1 AND "template_items"."id" IN ('419cb7ec-ca3f-4911-8a00-bec20f5ca89c', 'a7ac1687-8cb5-4199-a03b-d7cc975a0387', 'd7d885b6-2a75-487a-918c-6f3abaae7df1', 'b1b0277c-632f-4fe1-82e5-d020ee313d5b') ORDER BY sort ASC  [["template_id", "f9f6bca2-cb84-4349-8546-ca38026db407"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.137975 #1852] DEBUG -- :   Account Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "c379e356-4cce-4de2-b1b4-984b773dd43e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.144421 #1852] DEBUG -- :   CACHE Template Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(templates.name) ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "f9f6bca2-cb84-4349-8546-ca38026db407"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.148992 #1852] DEBUG -- :   CACHE Template Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(templates.name) ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "f9f6bca2-cb84-4349-8546-ca38026db407"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.156300 #1852] DEBUG -- :   TemplateItem Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "template_items".* FROM "template_items" WHERE "template_items"."template_id" = $1 ORDER BY sort ASC  [["template_id", "f9f6bca2-cb84-4349-8546-ca38026db407"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.171567 #1852] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.9ms)  UPDATE "template_items" SET "sort" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "template_items"."id" = $3  [["sort", 2], ["updated_at", "2018-02-20 19:22:56.167142"], ["id", "d7d885b6-2a75-487a-918c-6f3abaae7df1"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.175072 #1852] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "template_items" SET "sort" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "template_items"."id" = $3  [["sort", 1], ["updated_at", "2018-02-20 19:22:56.172797"], ["id", "a7ac1687-8cb5-4199-a03b-d7cc975a0387"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.176305 #1852] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  COMMIT
I, [2018-02-20T20:22:56.183481 #1852]  INFO -- : Rendered TemplateSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (2.97ms)
```

Here is the log when the action correctly returns the new data - I have marked the differences (1) and (2):

```
I, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.490513 #3087]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::TemplatesController#update as JSON
 ...parameters...
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.499201 #3087] DEBUG -- :   User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "rmcsharry+owner@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.706520 #3087] DEBUG -- :   Template Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(templates.name) ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.727668 #3087] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.777126 #3087] DEBUG -- :   TemplateItem Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "template_items".* FROM "template_items" WHERE "template_items"."template_id" = $1 AND "template_items"."id" IN ('ff034c14-252f-4366-9b31-526b5211e92b', '4e6ec7ef-ba53-4ec2-ab2e-97dd3b2c41bc', '3628b6ca-cddb-4d65-a6c3-86dfdcaa92f4', '35e61d68-143c-4bac-ab15-fbbb2b3f13d1') ORDER BY sort ASC  [["template_id", "c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.820226 #3087] DEBUG -- :   Account Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "c379e356-4cce-4de2-b1b4-984b773dd43e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.847928 #3087] DEBUG -- :   CACHE Template Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(templates.name) ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.850995 #3087] DEBUG -- :   CACHE Template Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(templates.name) ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(1) D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.856858 #3087] DEBUG -- :   Template Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."name" = $1 AND ("templates"."id" != $2) AND "templates"."account_id" = 'c379e356-4cce-4de2-b1b4-984b773dd43e' AND "templates"."template_type" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["name", "Daffy"], ["id", "c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948"], ["template_type", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.863415 #3087] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "template_items" SET "sort" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "template_items"."id" = $3  [["sort", 2], ["updated_at", "2018-02-20 19:52:47.859495"], ["id", "3628b6ca-cddb-4d65-a6c3-86dfdcaa92f4"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.865969 #3087] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "template_items" SET "sort" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "template_items"."id" = $3  [["sort", 3], ["updated_at", "2018-02-20 19:52:47.864044"], ["id", "35e61d68-143c-4bac-ab15-fbbb2b3f13d1"]]
D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.868568 #3087] DEBUG -- :    (2.0ms)  COMMIT
(2) D, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.918381 #3087] DEBUG -- :   TemplateItem Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "template_items".* FROM "template_items" WHERE "template_items"."template_id" = $1 ORDER BY sort ASC  [["template_id", "c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948"]]
I, [2018-02-20T20:52:47.930257 #3087]  INFO -- : Rendered TemplateSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (17.22ms)
```

Notice the differences:

(1) the log shows a 'Template Exists' message

(2) after the commit Rails reloads the template_items to get the updated data from the database.

I know that I can fix this and force the update action to always do (2) and reload the template_items child objects:

**templates_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    if @template.update(template_params)
      @template.template_items.reload
      render json: @template, serializer: TemplateSerializer, status: :ok 
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(@template.errors), status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

But why do I need to do that if Rails has the ability (sometimes) to figure that out on its own? Although the cache is used in both calls, in the correct second example Rails has figured out it needs to reload the child objects after the database was updated, but not in the first case.

So what I am trying to understand is what controls this behaviour. It seems to me that it must be related to the `before_save` action in the `Template` model, since that action only fires for the 2nd case (template_type is 'template') and not the 1st (template_type is 'checklist'). In other words it seems when that action fires it 'changes' the behaviour of the update action.

So my questions are:

1. Why the different behaviour for the same action? If it is the
   before_save, then why?
2. Why in the correct case does the log show Template Exists (since it
   does exist in both cases)?
3. How does Rails know to reload the updated children in the correct case
   but not in the incorrect case?

** UPDATE **

Here is the **template_serializer.rb**

```
class TemplateSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, 
    :account_id,
    :name,
    :info,
    :title,
    :template_type,
    :status

  has_many :template_items, include_nested_associations: true
end
```

Comment: I think the reason it reloads on the second is because the before save "changes" the template (the exists is a `name` uniqueness validation almost certainly) since the template is "changed" it reloads and reloads it's children where as when the template is unchanged and only the children change it does not need to reload. I would recommend your known work around to reload always to avoid this inconsistency

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks, that does seem to make sense. I would like to try to find an official reference in the docs if possible...will keep looking. And yes for now I think I need the workaround...and probably forever :)

Comment: I expect something is happening in your serializer if you are experiencing the model being reloaded automatically. Could you include that code?

Comment: @CodyGustafson I don't think it's that, but I added the serializer code.

Comment: Yeah,  pretty slim serializer. I am now expecting updating the parent may be invalidating the association cache.

Comment: @rmcsharry, I finally got the chance to get on my laptop again (instead of my phone). I expect my updated answer to be surprising to you, but should help you fix this behavior.

Comment: @CodyGustafson Yes, you are right and I was surprised. Thanks for taking the time to update the answer - I will change my code as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are requesting the items prior changing the sort. This means that the array of items that you have will no longer be sorted since you changed the property they are sorted on. Put another way, after you modify them, there isn't another query which returns the correct order.

So, I'll say the possible solutions are:

1. Reload the items after you mutate the sort.
2. Don't pull the items until after you mutate the sort.
3. Mutate the order of `template_items` based on sort values that changed.

The tradeoffs:

1. You have 2 select queries as well as the updates.
2. You have to update the records using `TemplateItem.update(id, sort: sort)` with all those updates within a transaction prior to selecting the records.
3. If you aren't rendering all the results, or decide not to in the future, it is possible that you will be modifying an item which will no longer be on the page. And, possibly other issues.

---

> Why the different behaviour for the same action? If it is the before_save, then why?

The before_save is requesting `template_items` prior to them being saved. Otherwise, `template_items` doesn't get called until the serializer renders them. Note, that this means your `before_save` callback isn't performing the way you want it to since it is modifying the status based on the previous values.

> Why in the correct case does the log show Template Exists (since it does exist in both cases)?

```
SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE
"templates"."name" = 'Daffy' AND 
("templates"."id" != 'c965c3ed-ace2-43af-9abd-f85392bdb948') AND 
"templates"."account_id" = 'c379e356-4cce-4de2-b1b4-984b773dd43e' AND
"templates"."template_type" = 0
 LIMIT 1
```

Looking at the SQL, this looks like a validation to ensure name is unique across templates and type.

> How does Rails know to reload the updated children in the correct case but not in the incorrect case?

Rails does not know. It is only loading them once in both cases. Just, with the before_save it is running before the records are updated.

### Summary:

The easiest way to fix this timing issue would using a different callback which fires after updating the children such as `after_update`.

Comment: Thanks for all this info. I took out the before_save and now I get the same behaviour, so that answers the question that it is causing the different behaviour - not the serializer.